# Add order number to a string in WooCommerce email body template

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-templates

I'm trying to change the on-hold email to include the order number in the introduction.

I've added "$order->get_id()" to show the order number. Not quite working. Any ideas?

```
<p><?php esc_html_e( 'Thanks for your order. Your order number is $order->get_id(). Below you can find the contents of your order.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to concatenate the order number in the string… You can use, in a better way, `printf()` and the `WC_Order` method `get_order_number()` as follows:

```
<p><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Thanks for your order. Your order number is %s. Below you can find the contents of your order.', 'woocommerce' ), $order->get_order_number() ); ?></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because it is now seen as part of the string, it's missing the concatenation operator `('.')`

More info: [String Operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Use it like this instead

```
<p><?php esc_html_e( 'Thanks for your order. Your order number is ' . $order->get_id() . ' Below you can find the contents of your order.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>
```

Example:

Not

```
'First part of string $myvar Second part of string';
```

But

```
'First part of string' . $myvar . 'Second part of string';
```

---

---

EDIT

Another option: see [Loic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64425000/11987538),
double answer, posted simultaneously